# How do I get a list, sorted by frequency, in R

Tags: r, sorting

I'm trying to get a list, sorted by frequency, from a data frame.

```
data <- read.csv('ads.csv')
write.table(summary(data$Publication.Name), quote = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

I'm not sure summary() is really the best way to get frequencies, I'm open to a better way. How can I sort this by most frequent first?

Comment: try `table` for frequencies. also make your [question reproducible.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would use `table`, for example

```
yourdata <- sample(1:10,100,replace=T) 
x <- sort(table(yourdata),decreasing=T)
write.csv(x,"mytable.csv",quote=F)
```